# problem with filling a pointer array with random numbers initialised by calloc

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, crash, calloc

1. my program should create 10 Vectors each with a random dimension between 1 and 10 and each dimension filled with random numbers between 0 and 24.

   ```
   int * makeVector(int dimension) {
     int * Vector = NULL;

     Vector = (int*) calloc(dimension - 1, sizeof(int));
     if (NULL == Vector) exit(1);

     srand(time(0));

     for (int i = 0; i < (dimension - 1); i++) {
       Vector[i] = rand() % 25;
     }

     return Vector; 
   }

   int main() {
     srand(time(0));

     for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       printf("-----%d. Vector-----\n", i);
       fflush(stdout);
       int dimension = (rand() % 10) + 1;
       int *Vector = NULL;

       memcpy(Vector, makeVector(dimension), dimension);

       for (int k = 1; k <= dimension; k++) {
         printf("%d. Dimension: %d\n", k, Vector[k - 1]);
       }
       if (Vector) {
         free(Vector);
         Vector = NULL;
       }
     }
     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. My Problem: There are no warnings and no errors showing up! 
   Though the For-Loop in the makeVector function doesnt seems to work at all.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < (dimension - 1); i++) {
        Vector[i] = rand() % 25;
   }
   ```

int i only equals 0 the first time and nothing happens. The For-Loop skips and the program gets terminated with the exit value:-1.073.741.819

PS: Im pretty new to programming ... could interpreted the Debugger wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `memcpy(Vector, makeVector(dimension), dimension);`  --> here `Vector` is `NULL` and you are writing to it -- which is undefined behavior.  Why not `Vector = makeVector(dimension)` ?

Comment: do `srand(time(0));` only one time on your program else you will retry the same values becayse no chance to move to an other second

Comment: i also don't understand why you are subtracting 1 from dimension in `makeVector`.  That doesn't look right

Comment: @MFisherKDX The 1. dimension should be the 0. position in the array. 10th dimension is on array pos. 9

Comment: arrays are zero-indexed in C.  So you have an off by one error.  Inside `makeVector` you are allocating space for `dimension-1` elements.  But then in `main` you are accessing `dimension` elements.

Comment: why to make simple ? ^^

Comment: @MFisherKDX yes but i also substract one from int k in the main function. So it works again. I admit this is kinda weird programming ^^. I keep that in mind

Comment: No.  When you use `calloc` to allocate space for N elements, the valid indices are 0 to N-1 inclusive.  In `makeVector` you are allocating space for `dimension-1` ints ... from Vector[0] to Vector[dimension-2].  In `main` you are indexing `dimension` ints ... from Vector[0] to Vector[dimension-1].

Comment: @bruno -- I don't understand what you mean by: "why to make simple ? ^^"

Comment: it was a joke, I speak about the _dimension_ management with the -1/+1 and finally lost the last entry, this is a little _Shadock_ ^^

Comment: Yes.  Needs to simplify and index from 0.  Otherwise the OP will confuse himself/herself.

Comment: @MFisherKDX and worst confuse us :-)

Comment: @MFisherKDX Ok TY very much. Now i get it^^. Its just the way calloc works ... i see. TY for your help bruno and MFisherKDX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your main problem is :

```
memcpy(Vector, makeVector(dimension), dimension);
```

while *Vector* is a null pointer, so the behavior is undefined

do

```
Vector = makeVector(dimension);
```

---

An other problem is to redo `srand(time(0));` is *makeVector*, the execution time is almost nothing so you reinitialize the random generation to give you again the same values (there is almost no change to have the time changing).

Do `srand(time(0));` only one time during the execution

---

In

```
for (int k = 1; k <= dimension; k++) {
  printf("%d. Dimension: %d\n", k, Vector[k - 1]);
}
```

you access to the non initialized last entry of the vector because in *makeVector* :

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dimension - 1); i++) {
    Vector[i] = rand() % 25;
 }
```

must be

```
for (int k = 1; k < dimension; k++) {
  printf("%d. Dimension: %d\n", k, Vector[k - 1]);
}
```

or of course modify the initialization loop to not lost the last entry

---

Compilation and execution after the changes :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
-----1. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 18
2. Dimension: 21
3. Dimension: 22
4. Dimension: 21
5. Dimension: 2
6. Dimension: 0
7. Dimension: 24
-----2. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 20
2. Dimension: 24
3. Dimension: 13
-----3. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 3
-----4. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 5
2. Dimension: 24
3. Dimension: 10
4. Dimension: 4
5. Dimension: 20
-----5. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 19
2. Dimension: 7
3. Dimension: 24
4. Dimension: 24
5. Dimension: 16
6. Dimension: 11
-----6. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 10
2. Dimension: 14
3. Dimension: 17
4. Dimension: 9
5. Dimension: 9
-----7. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 9
2. Dimension: 8
3. Dimension: 19
4. Dimension: 9
5. Dimension: 7
-----8. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 6
2. Dimension: 8
3. Dimension: 23
-----9. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 14
2. Dimension: 13
3. Dimension: 12
4. Dimension: 13
-----10. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 18
2. Dimension: 10
3. Dimension: 3
4. Dimension: 12
5. Dimension: 20
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==29590== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29590== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29590== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29590== Command: ./a.out
==29590== 
-----1. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 21
2. Dimension: 16
3. Dimension: 3
4. Dimension: 11
5. Dimension: 11
6. Dimension: 8
7. Dimension: 13
8. Dimension: 8
9. Dimension: 23
-----2. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 11
2. Dimension: 3
3. Dimension: 5
4. Dimension: 21
5. Dimension: 18
6. Dimension: 4
-----3. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 20
2. Dimension: 15
3. Dimension: 4
4. Dimension: 17
5. Dimension: 0
6. Dimension: 2
7. Dimension: 21
-----4. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 24
2. Dimension: 6
3. Dimension: 20
4. Dimension: 10
5. Dimension: 1
6. Dimension: 19
-----5. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 19
2. Dimension: 24
3. Dimension: 19
-----6. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 7
2. Dimension: 10
-----7. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 5
2. Dimension: 6
3. Dimension: 4
4. Dimension: 10
5. Dimension: 11
6. Dimension: 2
7. Dimension: 4
-----8. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 0
2. Dimension: 1
-----9. Vector-----
1. Dimension: 6
2. Dimension: 18
3. Dimension: 12
4. Dimension: 10
5. Dimension: 16
-----10. Vector-----
==29590== 
==29590== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29590==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29590==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 1,212 bytes allocated
==29590== 
==29590== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29590== 
==29590== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29590== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```